# Recursion results in nested lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

Running my function `frisbeeSort()` always results in the list being sorted but with each item being in a nested list. I would like to recursively alter the original list instead of using a temp list.

```
def frisbeeSort(n):
    index = n.index(min(n))
    if len(n) == 1:
        return n[0]
    else:
        n[0:index + 1] = n[index::-1]
        n = [n[0], frisbeeSort(n[1:])]
    return n

list1 = [12, 42, 34, 12, 76, 45, 13, 98, 234, 1]
```

I expect

```
[1, 12, 12, 13, 34, 42, 45, 76, 98, 234]
```

but I keep getting

```
[1, [12, [12, [13, [34, [42, [45, [76, [98, 234]]]]]]]]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return an item, not a list when `len(n) == 1`. You are also concatenating the two lists incorrectly. Try this:

```
def frisbeeSort(n):
    index = n.index(min(n))
    if len(n) == 1:
        return [n[0]]
    else:
        n[0:index + 1] = n[index::-1]
        n = [n[0]] + frisbeeSort(n[1:])
    return n

list1 = [12, 42, 34, 12, 76, 45, 13, 98, 234, 1]
print(frisbeeSort(list1))
```

output:

```
[1, 12, 12, 13, 34, 42, 45, 76, 98, 234]
```

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to recursively alter the original list instead of using a
>   temp list

Although the accepted answer addresses the "nested list" issue, I don't believe it addresses the above expectation.  That is, if you do:

```
list1 = [12, 42, 34, 12, 76, 45, 13, 98, 234, 1]
print(frisbeeSort(list1))
print(list1)
```

You get:

```
> python3 test.py
[1, 12, 12, 13, 34, 42, 45, 76, 98, 234]
[1, 234, 98, 13, 45, 76, 12, 34, 42, 12]
>
```

Where `list1` is altered but remains unsorted.  Here's one way to go about the problem of sorting the list in-place using the OP's algorithm:

```
def frisbeeSort(n, start=0):
    if start < len(n):
        index = n.index(min(n[start:]), start)
        n[start:index + 1] = n[start:index + 1][::-1]
        frisbeeSort(n, start + 1)

list1 = [12, 42, 34, 12, 76, 45, 13, 98, 234, 1]
frisbeeSort(list1)
print(list1)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
[1, 12, 12, 13, 34, 42, 45, 76, 98, 234]
>
```

> could you please explain what exactly changes the original list
>   instead of returning a sorted list?

There are two things that allow this to happen.  First, the (defaulted) second `start` argument:

```
def frisbeeSort(n, start=0):
```

which allows us to preserve the initial elements that are sorted on the recursive call:

```
 frisbeeSort(n, start + 1)
```

and tells us where to begin our new minimum search:

```
 index = n.index(min(n[start:]), start)
```

etc.  Second, the assignment back into the array itself:

```
n[start:index + 1] = n[start:index + 1][::-1]
```

We're replacing the remaining unsorted elements with the same values reversed.  The temporary array on right gets tossed and the original gets updated.

Comment: could you please explain what exactly changes the original list instead of returning a sorted list?

Comment: @IonicGolem36, I've added some explanation of this to my answer -- let me know if you still have questions.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `[n[0], frisbeeSort(n[1:])]`, it creates a two-element list in which the first element is `n[0]` and the second one is the value returned from `frisbeeSort(n[1:])` (which is a list). If you want to join them into a flat list, you can write `[n[0]] + frisbeeSort(n[1:])`.